# How to use fnr.exe?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I'm using fnr.exe (https://findandreplace.codeplex.com).

I have it in a bat file.  The file I'm working on is in the same folder as the bat file.  I've tried the following:

```
fnr.exe --cl --find "text1" --replace "text2" --dir "\" --fileMask "app.config"
```

but get this error:

> --fileMask required option is missing

Any one know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the program I can't be sure, but the standard rules to process command line arguments will see your command line as

```
                                                     | Here is the problem
                                                     v
fnr.exe --cl --find "text1" --replace "text2" --dir "\" --fileMask "app.config"
(.....) (..) (....) (.....) (.......) (.....) (...) (.........................)
```

A single backslash followed by a quote is a escaped quote that is included in the argument.

Try with

```
fnr.exe --cl --find "text1" --replace "text2" --dir "\." --fileMask "app.config"
```

Comment: That makes sense.  The \. doesn't work.  Also tried two quotes, which didn't work either.

Comment: @4thSpace, if the `--dir` argument should do reference to the current folder (???) then you can try with  `--dir "."` or `--dir "%cd%\."` or if inside a batch file `--dir "%~dp0\."`